# Geotiff: convert tiff from EPSG:3031 to EPSG:4326

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geotiff

I have a geotiff image that has covert type `EPSG:3031`. And it has not that system of coordinate that I needed and has weight **100 - 400 MB**.

For example, file that has big weight has bound box with folowing coordinates:

`[2577320.2719637007, 1798267.0376260928, 3056480.2719637007, 2178787.037626093]`

I need to display it on a leaflet map as a layer. But before, I guess, I need to convert it. How can I do it? And does any `npm` libraires could do it?

Comment: You gotta either a) use proj4leaflet so that your whole leaflet map is in EPSG:3031 or b) reproject the geotiff ahead of time, using any of the available GIS tools for that. See e.g. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/85954/how-to-reproject-geotiff-correctly

Comment: @IvanSanchez I've finished with **a** an hour ago :D yes, seems there is no alternative option except do convert my tif image to another. Tried to display tif in 228 mb - Chrome stucked and then I got an exception `Out of memory`. Thanks for reply

Comment: Split it into smaller images, e.g. `gdal2tiles` or heavier options like geoserver or mapproxy.